# Vue.js call method on service in component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've made a component in [Vue.js 2.0](https://vuejs.org/) that delete's things with [sweetalert](https://limonte.github.io/sweetalert2/). It looks like this:

```
export default {
    props:['service', 'method', 'id'],

    methods: {
        destroy() {
            swal({
                title: 'Weet u het zeker?',
                type: 'warning',
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonText: 'Ja verwijder',
                cancelButtonText: 'Stop!',
                confirmButtonColor: '#34495e',
                cancelButtonColor: '#ff3860',
            }).then (() => {
                this.service[this.method](this.id)
                    .then(() => {
                        swal({
                            title: 'Verwijderd',
                            text: 'Succesvol verwijderd',
                            type: 'success',
                            showConfirmButton: false,
                            timer: 2000
                        });

                        location.reload();
                    })

                    .catch(() => {
                        swal({
                            title: 'Fout',
                            text: 'Heeft u voldoende rechten?',
                            type: 'error',
                            showConfirmButton: false,
                            timer: 2000
                        });
                    });
            })
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that this:

```
this.service[this.method](this.id)
```

Is not working. I'm passing the props like this:

```
<destroy :service="Service" method="destroy" :id="relation.id"></destroy>
```

The destroy method in the service class looks like this:

```
destroy(id) {
    return axios.delete('/relaties/' + id);
}
```

In my vue debug bar the destroy component looks like this:

[image]

The error in my console:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
    at eval (eval at ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js?{"cacheDirectory":true,"presets":[["env",{"modules":false,"targets":{"browsers":["> 2%"],"uglify":true}}]]}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./resources/assets/js/components/shared/Destroy.vue (app.js?id=d89bceb…:319), <anonymous>:27:54)
    at <anonymous>
```

Any idea how I could fix this?

Answer (score 0):

```
    export default {
        props:['service', 'method', 'id'],

        methods: {
            destroy() {
                var self = this;
                swal({
                    title: 'Weet u het zeker?',
                    type: 'warning',
                    showCancelButton: true,
                    confirmButtonText: 'Ja verwijder',
                    cancelButtonText: 'Stop!',
                    confirmButtonColor: '#34495e',
                    cancelButtonColor: '#ff3860',
                }).then (() => {
                    self.service[self.method](self.id)
                        .then(() => {
                            swal({
                                title: 'Verwijderd',
                                text: 'Succesvol verwijderd',
                                type: 'success',
                                showConfirmButton: false,
                                timer: 2000
                            });

                            location.reload();
                        })

                        .catch(() => {
                            swal({
                                title: 'Fout',
                                text: 'Heeft u voldoende rechten?',
                                type: 'error',
                                showConfirmButton: false,
                                timer: 2000
                            });
                        });
                })
            }
        }
    }
```

You should create global link to "this" variable, in SWAL callback function "this" is replaced by local SWAL var.